# Get data using inner join on three tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to get the name of avatars which belong to active players and also the players whose email starts with "a".

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM AVATAR 
  INNER JOIN PLAYERAVATAR ON PLAYERAVATAR.PLAYER_ID = PLAYERAVATAR.AVATAR_ID 
  INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER.ACTIVE = 1;
```

I have this but it doesn't work. I'm not really good at this so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
|  AVATAR   |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
| AVATAR_ID | NUMBER(38,0)       | No  |  | 1 |  |
| NAME      | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 2 |  |
| DOB       | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 3 |  |
| HOARD     | NUMBER(38,0)       | Yes |  | 4 |  |
| STRENGH   | NUMBER             | Yes |  | 5 |  |
| GENDER    | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 6 |  |
| SPECIES   | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 7 |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+

+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
|  PLAYER   |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
| PLAYER_ID | NUMBER(38,0)       | No  |  | 1 |  |
| NAME      | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 2 |  |
| EMAIL     | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 3 |  |
| ACTIVE    | NUMBER(38,0)       | Yes |  | 4 |  |
| PASSWORD  | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 5 |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
+--------------+--------------+-----+--+---+--+
| PLAYERAVATAR |              |     |  |   |  |
+--------------+--------------+-----+--+---+--+
| PLAYER_ID    | NUMBER(38,0) | Yes |  | 1 |  |
| AVATAR_ID    | NUMBER(38,0) | Yes |  | 2 |  |
+--------------+--------------+-----+--+---+--+
```

Comment: 1. "I have this but it doesn't work." What exactly does not work? 2. "players whose email starts with a". I don't see such criteria anywhere in your query. 3. NAME exists in both AVATAR and PLAYER. Don't you want to tell the DBMS which of the two you want to Show?

Comment: Is there a reason why you join the tables rather than look up players with `EXISTS` or `IN`?

Comment: One player can have several avatars and each avatar can be used by several players. But you want to show just the avatar names, right? And in case one avatar is used by two active players, you want to show the avatar name once or twice?

Comment: The link table is to resolve the many-to-many relationship issue. One player can own many avatars but one avatar can't be owned by multiple players.

Comment: But 1 player per avatar is not many-to-many, but 1-to-many. You should drop your bridge table `PLAYERAVATAR` and add the `PLAYER_ID` to your `AVATAR` table. Thus you'd guarantee consistency (that an avatar can only belong to one player) and get your queries much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    AVATAR.NAME 
FROM 
    AVATAR 
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYERAVATAR ON PLAYERAVATAR.AVATAR_ID = AVATAR.AVATAR_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYER ON PLAYER.PLAYER_ID = PLAYERAVATAR.PLAYER_ID
WHERE 
    PLAYER.ACTIVE = 1
AND 
    PLAYER.EMAIL LIKE 'a%' ;
```

---

In case you want to select **Unique Avatar Names**, you can use `DISTINCT`, something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AVATAR.NAME 
FROM 
    AVATAR 
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYERAVATAR ON PLAYERAVATAR.AVATAR_ID = AVATAR.AVATAR_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYER ON PLAYER.PLAYER_ID = PLAYERAVATAR.PLAYER_ID
WHERE 
    PLAYER.ACTIVE = 1
AND 
    PLAYER.EMAIL LIKE 'a%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error because column `name` is in more than one table.

You should use an alias.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    P.NAME 
FROM 
    AVATAR A
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYERAVATAR PL ON PL.PLAYER_ID = A.PLAYER_ID
INNER JOIN 
    PLAYER P ON P.ACTIVE = 1 AND P.PLAYER_ID  = A.PLAYER_ID
WHERE 
    SUBSTR(P.EMAIL, 1, 1) = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select a.NAME       from AVATAR   a
    join PLAYERAVATAR  pa on a.AVATAR_ID =pa.AVATAR_ID 
    join PLAYER   p on pa.PLAYER_ID    =p.PLAYER_ID   
    where p.ACTIVE = 1 and p.EMAIL     like 'a%'
```

if you want distinct avatar name you can use

```
 select distinct(a.NAME)
```

Comment: @HamidHosseini : If this worked , please check right to the answer

Answer (score 0):

From our brief discussion in your request's comment section it becomes clear that your data model doesn't actually match the requirements. You say that an avatar belongs to only one player. So store the player_id in the avatar record and drop the bridge table.

```
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
|  PLAYER   |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
| PLAYER_ID | NUMBER(38,0)       | No  |  | 1 |  |
| NAME      | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 2 |  |
| ...       |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+

+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
|  AVATAR   |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
| AVATAR_ID | NUMBER(38,0)       | No  |  | 1 |  |
| NAME      | VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) | Yes |  | 2 |  |
| PLAYER_ID | NUMBER(38,0)       | No  |  | 3 |  |
| ...       |                    |     |  |   |  |
+-----------+--------------------+-----+--+---+--+
```

The query becomes:

```
select name
from avatar
where player_id in
(
  select player_id
  from player
  where active = 1
  and email like 'a%'
);
```